# How to load data from my database through HTML/JS code (like ex. Google AdSense/Analytics, Disqus etc)?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, ajax

I have some data in my database. I would like to offer to my readers a posiblity to load data from my database on their website - something very similar does Google with - for example - Google Analytics, where is provided to users a piece of HTML code that users put into the HTML code of their websites and on the spot where is the code from the Google part included are displayed the respective data.

I have never been working with the technique that is needed for this purpose, so I am not sure how to implement it/what is needed for it.

I would be grateful for pointing me to the right direction.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement an API

http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem

the idea to send data RESTfully as JSON or XML
then parse that the using javascript (jquery,angular,etc..) to display it as HTML

This main challenge in creating an API is authentication. 
You take a look at Oauth and Doorkeeper gem for rails